# How to sort each column according to the observations in the same output?

Tags: r, sorting

I have this dataframe:

```
data.frame( obs= c("A","B","C","D","E"),
            Var1 = c(3.7, 7.8, 8.9, 7.0, 3.4),
            Var2 = c(2.7, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0),
            Var3 = c(9.1, 1.5, 2.7, 9.0, 5.0))
```

to order as I need, I did it like this:

```
rbind(
  data.frame( obs= c("A","B","C","D","E"),
              Var1 = c(3.7, 7.8, 8.9, 7.0, 3.4),
              Var2 = rep("",5),
              Var3 = rep("",5)) %>%  
    arrange(-Var1),
  
  data.frame( obs= c("A","B","C","D","E"),
              Var1 = rep("",5),
              Var2 = c(2.7, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0),
              Var3 = rep("",5)) %>%  
    arrange(-Var2),
  
  data.frame( obs = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
              Var1 = rep("",5),
              Var2 = rep("",5),
              Var3 = c(9.1, 1.5, 2.7, 9.0, 5.0)) %>%  
    arrange(-Var3)
)
```

output:

[image]

How to make this process more efficient and generic for multiple observations and columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the data in long format, `arrange` the data in descending order, create a row number column and get the data in wide format.

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries you may do this as -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -obs) %>%
  arrange(name, desc(value)) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)

#  obs    Var1  Var2  Var3
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 C       8.9  NA    NA  
# 2 B       7.8  NA    NA  
# 3 D       7    NA    NA  
# 4 A       3.7  NA    NA  
# 5 E       3.4  NA    NA  
# 6 B      NA     8    NA  
# 7 A      NA     2.7  NA  
# 8 E      NA     2    NA  
# 9 C      NA     1    NA  
#10 D      NA     1    NA  
#11 A      NA    NA     9.1
#12 D      NA    NA     9  
#13 E      NA    NA     5  
#14 C      NA    NA     2.7
#15 B      NA    NA     1.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to keep the original column order? for example, a  column "var10" would appear in the first column of the result.

Comment: "var10" should be the 1st column or the 10th one? Try changing the `arrange` line to `arrange(order(gtools::mixedorder(name)), desc(value))`

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution using `Map` and just the base package.

```
r <- do.call(rbind, 
             Map(\(x, y, z) {x <- x[y, ]; x[-c(1, z)] <- NA; x}, 
                 list(d), lapply(d[-1], order, decreasing=T), seq(ncol(d))[-1]))
r
#   obs Var1 Var2 Var3
# 3    C  8.9   NA   NA
# 2    B  7.8   NA   NA
# 4    D  7.0   NA   NA
# 1    A  3.7   NA   NA
# 5    E  3.4   NA   NA
# 21   B   NA  8.0   NA
# 11   A   NA  2.7   NA
# 51   E   NA  2.0   NA
# 31   C   NA  1.0   NA
# 41   D   NA  1.0   NA
# 12   A   NA   NA  9.1
# 42   D   NA   NA  9.0
# 52   E   NA   NA  5.0
# 32   C   NA   NA  2.7
# 22   B   NA   NA  1.5
```

#### Benchmark

This should be slightly more efficient.

```
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq      max neval cld
#   Map   876.396   900.545   970.8851   981.9155  1014.284   1145.8   100  a 
# dplyr 14744.610 14963.718 17997.4444 15439.0440 15752.575 241073.9   100   b
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(obs = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Var1 = c(3.7, 
7.8, 8.9, 7, 3.4), Var2 = c(2.7, 8, 1, 1, 2), Var3 = c(9.1, 1.5, 
2.7, 9, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```